# Adjusting the Width of a LinearLayout Children

Tags: android

I have a Layout to which i dynamically add rows to. Each row consists of a TextView and an EditText. Now the texts for the EditText are set at runtime, so i want them all to be neatly alligned like a inout form where a textfield is at the left and an edittext on the right.

This my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemsContainer.getChildCount(); i++) 
    {
        View v=itemsContainer.getChildAt(i);
        if(v instanceof ClickableButtonView)
        {
            TextView textView=((ClickableButtonView)v).getItem();
            if(textView.getWidth() > width)
            {
                width=textView.getWidth();
            }
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < itemsContainer.getChildCount(); i++) 
    {
        View v=itemsContainer.getChildAt(i);
        if(v instanceof ClickableButtonView)
        {
            TextView textView=((ClickableButtonView)v).getItem();
            textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }

    }
```

Now what happens is that my layout, with the textview collapses, and only the element on the right side takes up the complete space. I want to iterate over the LineraLyout, find the edittext that is taking the most room and set the all the edittext to take up the exact same room. Can this be done  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this method in a loop to set the style for your textviews with any weights required. Giving weight 1 to all will make it equal.

```
private void setStyle(TextView textView, float weight) {
    textView.setSingleLine(false);
    textView.setWidth(0);
    textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, weight));
    textView.setPadding(8, 0, 8, 0);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
}
```

Comment: I tried this. It does make the width of all the EditText equal, but it is squiching the text up. How can i change it to make each TextView equal to the widest text view ?

Comment: Cant measure the widest textview, but u can adjust the padding and if you dont want ur text to wrap but to cut, then remove the single line settings or set it to true.

Comment: Thanks i fiddled with the function abit and it works. Thanks alot for your help.